# only absolute positioning works in background image

Tags: css, background, alignment

I am trying to put a background to the main page (i.e. to the body), and to align the picture to the center right of the page, but all the arguments I found for background-position (like center right, or 90% 50%) have no effect, the picture always ends up in the top left corner. Only absolute positioning (like background-position: 1000px 100px;) seems to have an effect.

Here is my code:

```
body
{
    background-image:url(images/bg.png);
    background-position:1000px 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:95%;
    color:#333;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Do you know the cause of this problem ?

Comment: `center right` is working fine on your code. http://jsfiddle.net/H2X2L/

Comment: oh never mind I found the problem: the image actually contained a lot of blank space... stupid mistake from me sorry

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
background: url(<images goes here>) no-repeat right center fixed
```

Comment: This literally translates to the code he posted, but with the wrong background-position.

Comment: How does background-position:1000px 100px equal background-position:right center exactly?

Comment: Fair enough, it doesn't. But if you re-read the question he said that he already tried `background-position: center right` without any effect. The code he provided does work though as Suresh Ponnukalai pointed out, so there's definately something else at play.